# Unable to pass color from parent widget to child

Tags: flutter, dart

**Minimal reproducible code**:

```dart
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: FooPage()));

class FooPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(textTheme: TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF123456)))),
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) => ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Button'),
            onPressed: () => Bar.show(context), // Passing new context which has 123456 color
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Bar {
  static void show(BuildContext context) {
    print('color1: ${Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2?.color}'); // This is 123456 color

    showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      pageBuilder: (context, _, __) {
        print('color2: ${Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2?.color}'); // But this is not
        return FlutterLogo();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm passing `FF123456` color to `Bar.show()` but for some reasons it is not getting that color in the `pageBuilder` callback.

---

**NOTE:** I don't want to know how I can make it work, it's very simple. I just want to know what's wrong in the above code, why is it not working as expected?

Comment: probably of `context` ?

Comment: check `showGeneralDialog` [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/18116933e7/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart#L2007): it pushes a new `Route` that is out of scope of your local `Theme`

Comment: @pskink Yes, it does but that new `Navigator` too uses the passed `context`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: it uses passed `context` only for getting the `NavigatorState` - the `context` that is used inside `pageBuilder` is the different one that does not "see" your local `Theme`